# Hook Pi to 12V via UBEC

Tags: pi-3, power

Simple question:
Is there any danger for the Pi 3, if I hook it to a 12V Lead Acid battery via a UBEC, on the GPIO pins 2 and 4. Specifically this one: http://dx.com/p/hobbywing-5v-6v-3a-switch-mode-ultimate-bec-ubec-15149

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No problem . I have one of these UBEC Turnigy connected into 12V from my car and the output to my PI . Just remember to check if jumper is on correct voltage ,my UBEC has a jumper to choose 5V or 6V output . Also choose an UBEC with 2 or more AMPs output.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/rpi_SCH_3b_1p2_reduced.pdf

Never use GPIO as voltage input. 
There is no fuse or protection in that case.

See link above schematic-left-top for more voltage-in points.

Good luck.